# Ansible Join two variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, boto3

I have two variable definition files as follows

**vars.yml**

```yaml
aws_common_tags:
    Project: "{{ project_name }}"
    Application: "{{ application_name }}"
        Region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        Ansible: "Yes"
```

**instance.yml**

```yaml
ec2_instance_tags:
    environment_name: dev
```

Now in **task.yml** I am trying to create aws ec2 instance with all tags but its not working.

```yaml
ec2:
    key_name: "{{ keypair_name }}"
    instance_type: "{{ ec2_instance_type }}"
    instance_tags: "{{ aws_common_tags + ec2_instance_tags }}"
```

We are getting the following error:

```
"tags": {
        "Ansible": "Yes",
        "Application": "webserver",
        "Project": "document_upload",
        "Region": "us-west-2"
    },

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ aws_common_tags + ec2_instance_tags }}): unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'" }
```

Thanks

Comment: "{{ aws_common_tags}} {{ec2_instance_tags }}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) dictionaries. For example

```yaml
ec2:
    key_name: "{{ keypair_name }}"
    instance_type: "{{ ec2_instance_type }}"
    instance_tags: "{{ aws_common_tags|combine(ec2_instance_tags) }}"
```

The concatenation "`+`" would work with lists or strings that are treated as lists.

Comment: Thanks..Working fine now.